# JQuery check value lower and upper case

Tags: jquery

i am using this code to check for duplicate values in an array:

```
<?php
$return_arr = array();
$sql="SELECT * from customer where company <> '' group by company ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $return_arr[] = $result["company"];
}
$data = json_encode($return_arr);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ViewExistingCustomer").hide();

    var company_array = <?php echo $data; ?>;

    $('#company').on('keyup',function() {
        if($.inArray($(this).val(), company_array) !== -1) {
            $("#ViewExistingCustomer").attr("href", "customers?seq=");
            alert("This company name already exists on another customer.");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I am trying to make it do 2 things extra, i want to check values in the array no matter what case it is and what case has been typed in.

Also, there is a `sequence` in the MySQL table, how can i put this in my `href` edit line of code so it says `?seq=` then after = it will be the relevant `sequence` from the database / array

Comment: What do you mean by relevant sequence from the database/array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a for each and convert both values to lowercase and then compare them. If your $return_arr stores the company name and sequence in indexes 0 and 1 respectively as follows,

```
$return_arr[0] = ["company_name_1", "sequence"];
$return_arr[1] = ["company_name_2", "sequence"];
$return_arr[2] = ["company_name_3", "sequence"];
```

Then,

```
$.each(company_array, function(index, value) { 
  if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().equals(value[0].toLowerCase())) {
      $("#ViewExistingCustomer").attr("href", "customers?seq=" + value[1]);
      alert("This company name already exists on another customer.");
  }
});
```

Comment: where do i retrieve sequence from? if i changed $return_arr to include sequence as well as company from the database

Comment: could i do $return_arr[] = array('sequence' => $result["sequence"], 'company' => $result["company"]); then read from this?

Comment: @charlie Sure you can. Instead of numeric index access it by the key.

Comment: if i changed the PHP to that, how would i access sequence and company in the Jquery in the if statement

Comment: for example, the jquery array looks like var company_array = [{"sequence":"451","company":"Company 1"},{"sequence":"58","company":"Company 2"}];

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the values to lowercase and check to see if it exists somewhere in the array, but you will have to iterate over at least some of them.

```
var duplicates = company_array.some(function(val){
    return val.toLowerCase()===$(this).val().toLowerCase();
});
if(duplicates){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the JavaScript `.map()` method to convert every element in the array to lowercase or uppercase and then use the JavaScript array method `.indexOf()` to check for the value. You also want to add the value just accepted into the array or refresh the array so you don't add that value more than once:

```
$('#company').on('keyup',function() {
    var lArr = company_array.map(function(elm) {
        return elm.toLowerCase();
    });
    if( lArr.indexOf( this.value.toLowerCase() ) !== -1) {
        $("#ViewExistingCustomer").attr("href", "customers?seq=");
        alert("This company name already exists on another customer.");
    } else {
        company_array.push( this.value );
        //or do a post to add it and refresh company_array
    }
});
```

**NOTE**. Not sure if `keyup` is the appropriate event to use to fire a check. May be `input` might be a better event to use.